# iOS: Add address to new or existing contact with ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook, addressbookui

**Hello everyone**,

I am using the a **LocationManager, Geocoder and Placemark** to get the address of the user. Everything works fine.

After starting standardUpdates I use the following function:

```
[...]

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        self.placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

    NSString *placemarkCountry = self.placemark.country;
    NSString *placemarkPostalCode = self.placemark.postalCode;
    NSString *placemarkAdministrativeArea = self.placemark.administrativeArea;
    NSString *placemarkLocality = self.placemark.locality;
    NSString *placemarkThoroughfare = self.placemark.thoroughfare;
    NSString *placemarkSubThoroughfare = self.placemark.subThoroughfare;

    [...] //here I'm displaying the address, nothing special

}
```

Now I want to use an **ABUnknownPersonViewController** with **AddressBookUI** to add the address to a new or existing contact.

```
-(IBAction)addAddressToContactButtonPressed {

    [...]

}
```

The following picture shows, what it should looks like:

[image]

**Question**:
How the function *addAddressToContactButtonPressed* should look like? Can you help me with this? The function should use the NSStrings placemarkCountry, placemarkPostalCode, ... and open the ABUnknownPersonViewController with those information. The user should create a new contact with this address or add this address to a existing user.

I looked for some tutorials but couldn't find any useful (for me useful) help. I am a person learning by looking for tutorials and now I'm stuck.

```
Thank you for your help and your answers.
:-)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make an ABUnknownPersonViewController. Give it a delegate.
2. Create an ABPerson. Assign to that ABPerson (an ABRecord) any features you want it to have: in this case, the address.
3. Make the ABPerson the ABUnknownPersonViewController's `displayedPerson`.
4. Push the ABUnknownPersonViewController onto an existing UINavigationController.

Comment: So you are just going to have to learn, then. You have to walk before you can run.

Comment: I suppose you could try reading the section of my book that discusses ABUnknownPersonViewController: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch31.html#_abunknownpersonviewcontroller If you don't understand it, just keep reading the book backwards until you come to something you _do_ understand.